# Can I do distributed stress testing on Amazon rds oracle database?

Tags: performance-testing

We have an onpremise production database . We are planning to move it to cloud. What types of Performance testing can be done ?

1. Is it okay to start with stress testing first?
2. Shall I start with load testing and then do stress testing?
3. Can I do distributed testing for both load and stress test?

I am looking for a right approach to do performance testing on Database.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have [load tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) for existing on-premise database it worth starting with them against cloud deployment first, this way you will know if the RDS instance can handle the same load as the on-premise. If you don't plan onboarding new data/users/integrations and the results will be more or less the same you can stop there.
2. Then if needed you can kick off a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) to see if there are any bottlenecks and additionally measure the [scalability factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing)

   See [Performance Testing vs. Load Testing vs. Stress Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing) article to learn more about performance testing types and when they should be applied.
3. Distributed Testing is normally required when one load generator is not sufficient for conducting the needed load, if you have one load generator - monitor its CPU, RAM, Network, etc. usage to ensure that its not overloaded and can send requests to the database fast enough.